# Shortening a block of text

Tags: regex, textpad

This should be pretty damn simple, but I'm a newb at this. Let's say I'm dealing with a block of text 300+ characters long.

I want a regex string which will find any and all characters AFTER the first 200 characters, all the way to the end ($).

I want to delete everything past the first 200 characters. I'm dumping this data into a spreadsheet and don't need EVERYTHING.

==== update =====

Sorry guys, let be very specific. I'm not really using a programming language. (I'm in the app Ubot) Imagine you have a 300+ text block on a page in Textpad. You hit F8 and do a REPLACE. I check the box REGULAR EXPRESSION.

What would the Regular Expression I would use to FIND the first 200 characters, then REPLACE the remaining with NOTHING. (i.e. delete)

Comment: Do you want or not want the first 200 characters?

Comment: So you want to select the first 200 characters. `^.{200}` But do you need a regex for that or can you do that in code as well?

Comment: Would recommend playing with this to see if it works for you. https://regexr.com/4elge

Comment: Do you want to match the character AFTER the first 200 to delete them or those BEFORE to keep them?

Comment: Which language is the program in? There is usually a simple function in most computer languages to get a substring from a string.

Comment: I think this is why I'm screwing you guys up - I'm not using a standard language, more like Textpad. (see above)

Answer (score 0):

> I want a regex string which will find any and all characters AFTER the first 200 characters, all the way to the end ($).

This regex matches everything except the first 200 characters:

```
(?<=^[\s\S]{200})[\s\S]*$
```

If your regex engine supports `\K`, you can also do:

```
^[\s\S]{200}\K[\s\S]*$
```

> I want to delete everything past the first 200 characters

That sounds like you just want to match the first 200 characters, which can be done with this regex:

```
^[\s\S]{200}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second and third paragraphs are kind of contradictory. Try this [fork](https://regexr.com/4elgq) of @RugerSR9's that selects up to 200 characters (your input could be less than that, and I assume you still want it).

`^.{0,200}`

You may want to look at something other than a regex though, e.g., in pseudo-code, `string.Left(200)`.

Comment: OK, in Textpad (see above) ^.{0,25} does select the first 25 characters. Now I need to select the opposite till the end ($).

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I don't see any answers that are specific to the OPs question and it could help others in the future. Make sure the `Use POSIX regular expression syntax` is turned off in the preferences.

Search for:

`^\(.\{0,200\}\).*$`

And replace with:

`\1`

Explanation, this (`^\(.\{0,200\}\)`) will match upto the first 200 chars from the start of the line and put them into group `\1`. The remaining (`.*$` will match the rest of the chars on the line up until the end. The replacement expression replaces the entire line with the `\1` group that was matched.

Bonus if you need it a lot. Record it as a macro and then you can trim your files down with a few mouse clicks.

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose I use the block mode in textpad - there is no need to use regex.

Comment: Shortcut: Strg+Q, B